# Another word for return undamaged

Tags: single-word-requests

May I know if there is a single word that can replace the word "Return Undamaged" or "Return in Original form"?

**Details**

Jack borrow a item from Joe for 10 days. After the last day, Jack return the item to Joe. Joe check the item and confirm that the item is return in its original form and does not have any damages (such as scratches, tear, etc)

Comment: What's wrong with "return undamaged"? You cannot express everything in life in just 1 word, why always look for the simplest answer, when this delivers the message just fine? "Joe examined the item to confirm it has been returned undamaged."

Comment: I understand that life is complicated and require more than 1 word to describe to express it. I am just looking if there are really such a word that really exist. If such a word does not exist, it is fine.

Comment: I don't know about such a word. If someone has any idea, they sure will post an answer to help you, but I wouldn't count on such a word existing. I'd say "return undamaged" is as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps *restockable*, as in "item must be restockable".

However, it probably is better to separately emphasize "item must be returned" and "item must be in good condition when returned"; for example, "For refund of deposit, item must be restockable and punctual."

Comment: Yeah, I think that word - "restockable" quite fit into the picture that I am looking at. Thanks.